# Git merging strategy with different branches of submodules

Tags: git, merge, devops, git-submodules

## My current environment branches

- `master` which contains submodule `SMMaster`
- `dev`    which contains submodule `SMDev`

## My Current Merging Strategy when developing a feature

1. Create branch `feature` from `dev`
2. Add commits to `feature`
3. Merge `feature` to `dev` and submit for review
4. Once accepted, Merge `feature` to `master`
5. Now `master` contains submodule  `SMDEV`
6. So I change the submodule to `SMMaster` and commit to the `master`

### Issue

- Everytime I have to build a feature, I have to make another commit on the `master` branch just for swithching submodules. Any better merge strategy? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your workflow is, you use the `SMDev` branch for submodule. Behavior of git is correct and expected.

If you are creating the `feature` branch from dev, so then you have all changes from dev to merge to the master.

### Solution

#### cherry-pick

First solution if you are gonna stay with your workflow is `cherry-pick` instead of merging, but it is not how git is designed to work...

#### update workflow

Do you need the `SMDev` branch for submodule work with this workflow:

1. Create new `feature` branch off master
2. Update submodule, but never commit it. Skip the `git add` command for submodule.
3. Merge the `feature` to `dev`
4. Test properly in dev
5. Merge the `feature` to master

It introduced some manual work for developers

#### prepare-commit-msg hook

You can setup some hooks which can change your submodule branch when you are doing merge to master. For more information see this page: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_prepare_commit_msg

Comment: In the update workflow, How do you update submodule but never commit it? How you merge it to dev with uncommitted changes?

Comment: You create branch from master and you skip the `git add` command for git submodule, then it will not be in the pull request.